# How can I get only the decimal from a float in lua?

Tags: lua

How would I be able to do the following?

```
local d = getdecimal(4.2) --> .2
```

Comment: `math.fmod(4.2, 1)`. If you are not interested in negative numbers, you can also use the modulo operator: `4.2%1`.

Comment: @NicolBolas sorry but im not that good at this kind of stuff

Comment: So I, googling this 4 years later, found it helpful, even though it is a very simple question. It is rather "canonical". Also sometimes there are several answers, and it's good to see what the options are, and what best practice  is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're only working with numbers greater than 0, modulus is the best way to go:

```
print(4.2%1)
```

Otherwise the fmod function in the math library should do the trick.

```
print(math.fmod(4.2,1))
```

Comment: Something to note, modulo operator `%` will always return a positive number whereas `fmod` will not.

Comment: @Matthew "Assuming you're only working with numbers greater than 0"

Comment: Hence the "something to note" phrase, it's more information about the differences between the two.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a little bit of a non-paradigmatic approach to this by taking the number and turning it into a string:

```
function getDec(num)  
return tostring(num):match("%.(%d+)")
end

print(getDec(-3.2))
--2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getDecimal(inp)
 local x = tostring(inp)
 local found_decimal = false
 local output_stream = ""
    for i = 1, string.len(x) do
     if found_decimal == false then
      if string.sub(x, i+1, i+1) == "." then
       found_decimal = true
      end
    else
     output_stream = output_stream .. string.sub(x,i, i)
    end
  end
 return output_stream
end
```

What that does is it basically returns everything after the decimal it found as a string.

And if you want to turn the return back into a number do this:

```
return tonumber("0" .. output_stream)
```